# Deploy React Applications in a Servlet Environment

Tags: reactjs, servlets, war

I need to deploy react app in a servlet environment as a war to be deployed in tomcat container.

Steps that I did so far:

1) ran: > npm run build

2) took the content of build directory and put it under WebContent > dist folder under my war as bellow:

[image]

3) added an index.html under WebContent that redirects to the index inside dist folder:

```
<body onLoad="window.location.href='./dist'">
```

When deploying the war the redirect is performed and the browser is taking me to this location:
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/dist/

But there are errors in page:

[image]

(there are links to js files under "dist > static" folder, but the url does not include /MyApp/ and hence they can't be found)

## What had been tried:

1) following this link: https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/
I tried to set the basename of BrowserRouter to:

```
    import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        {/*<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || ''}>*/}
        <Router basename='/MyApp'>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={App} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/customize" component={ProjectCustomize} />
                {/*<Redirect path="*" to="/" />*/}
            </Switch>
        </Router>

        {/*<Login />*/}
        {/*<App/>*/}
    </div>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

But it didn't take affect!

2) following this issue: https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot/issues/397
I editied my public/index.html  ohave "." before %PUBLIC_URL%:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href=".%PUBLIC_URL%/tdf.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href=".%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
```

and seems that I passed the *.js files loading error and now getting issue with loading the css:

[image]

## Note

Even if I edit the links manually and try to access the site, no errors but nothing is displayed!

If I run "serve -s build" (normally, with no war) it works!

Answer (score 2):

In your react project open package.json file

add a key-value i.e, "homepage":"./" . It will look something like

```
    {
  "name": "your-app-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./"
.
.
.
}
```

Now run => npm run build and follow the same steps as you did.

Comment: Didn't help! BTW, when I replace the router entry points components to functions (as it described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58082196/getting-empty-screen-when-deploying-react-site-as-a-servlet-on-tomcat) it works. So why it's not working when the router is pointing to other components? is it a bug with BrowserRouter?

Comment: If I use HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter the site start responding, but when redirecting to other page I'm getting 404!

But still, HashRouter is ugly cause it's putting # in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to workaround this issue is by moving your React files directly under WebContent/ folder. It doesn't make sense to have an index.html redirecting to another index.html. If you can't do that for any reason, you might need to configure Tomcat Context Root (assuming version 8): https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html

You can even place these files outside your WAR and properly configure your Context. This [blog page](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/static-content-web-pages-images-tomcat-outside-war/) might give you some good insights:

> A Context element is added inside the Host element. Context has two attributes: **docBase** is the directory on disk that contains your static files and **path** is the URL that you want to serve the files on. Make sure that Tomcat has access to read the files in docBase

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I want to keep the outcome of build in a separated folder is to be organized and each time I generate a new build to delete the content of that folder and replace it with new one. Anyway, I tried locating files under WebContent directly and I faced the same.... I had to enter my index.html and change the urls to start with ./ (otherwise it was not finding static/css and static/js files)... But still after doing that, no errors are displayed and no content is diplayed at all on the screen!!

Comment: following this link: http://frugalisminds.com/react-js/deploy-react-js-in-tomcat/#comment-26210 which describes exactly the problem that I have, I tried implementing what was suggested there but still getting empty screen!

Comment: What do you see in the browser console? Any errors?

Comment: No errors. Blank screen
As it was explained from the link that I posted in my previous comment, the issue is with the BrowserRouter... it's not working as expected when the content is static

Comment: I just realized that the issue is with my own site! I went over steps from this link: https://www.megadix.it/blog/create-react-app-servlet/ and created a new app and it worked fine within a deployed war. I mean if the war is deployed to http://localhost:8080/my-war, and I use the router to navigate to about page then the baseUrl (my-war) will be ignored and the location will be switched to: http://localhost:8080/about. But I still can't find what is going wrong with my own site!

Answer (score 1):

1) The issue basically was with the env variable REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE that was reaching as undefined:

```
<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || ''}>
```

So in case it's not defined (I configured it in the pom.xml profile as it was explained in the posts that took the solution from, but seems I missed something), in that case use the app name hardcoded:

```
<Router basename={process.env.REACT_APP_ROUTER_BASE || '/MyApp'}>
```

2) Need to add this value to package.json: "homepage": "./"

Otherwise the generated index.html will use relative paths and scripts will not be found when loading

3) Don't use `window.location.href` for navigating, instead use `this.props.history.push`

Comment: I had the same issue, coming from the use of the "Router" functionality. The app works ok if you don't use the Router just by adding the value to **package.json**: 
`"homepage": "."` 
(and not "./"). However, the router needs this "basename" value to be defined. I got around this by defining it dynamically. Looking at the **App.js** file: 
`export const AppHistory = createBrowserHistory({
  basename: window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
});`